# Make RelativeLayout non-scrollable in horizontal scrollview

Tags: java, android, layout, view, horizontalscrollview

Hi i want to make a relative layout non scroll-able in horizontal scroll view.
Searched google a lot but did not got any good solution.
This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
     >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="1267dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <com.androidhive.musicplayer.VerticalSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="57dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
        <com.androidhive.musicplayer.VerticalSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="57dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_1" />

        <com.androidhive.musicplayer.VerticalSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_9" />

        <com.androidhive.musicplayer.VerticalSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/vertical_Seekbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_2" />

        <com.androidhive.musicplayer.VerticalSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_3" />

        <com.androidhive.musicplayer.VerticalSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/slider_label_1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_1" />



</RelativeLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

I want relativelayout with id "relative_layout4" to be always vsible.
only bottom part should scroll horizontally.

Please suggest me how to do it .

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @/krupal can u suggest how to do it ?

Comment: Why would you need to disable HorizontalScrollView? You should remove it rather than disabling it, if you don't need scrolling...

Comment: You could simply put your RelativeLayout outside the ScrollView. That way, only the ScrollView would scroll, and the RelativeLayout would remain fixed.

Comment: Thats not workng bro.i tried that first timee .scrllview not getting scrolled :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable any type of ScrollView, simply add `android:enabled="false"` to your ScrollView. This will disable scrolling.

But why would you need to disable HorizontalScrollView? You should remove it rather than disabling it, if you don't need scrolling...

**Edit:**

If you want to only enable scrolling in a certain part, just move the HorizontalScrollView to where you want.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <com.androidhive.musicplayer.VerticalSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.androidhive.musicplayer.VerticalSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />

            <com.androidhive.musicplayer.VerticalSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />

            <com.androidhive.musicplayer.VerticalSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />

            <com.androidhive.musicplayer.VerticalSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />

            <com.androidhive.musicplayer.VerticalSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/vertical_Seekbar_6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

It might still need some editing because I don't know how your views look like.

Comment: @Hussein.i want a lyout i whch uppper part show some textbutoons.that will be fixed and always visible......the bottm part shows some seekbars that r scrollable....thats why i asked how to make relative layout fixed ?

Comment: Alright, I understood you. But can you post your whole xml because I can't edit it as there are some stuff missing...

Comment: Sorry but its my complete xml.and working also....ful layout is getting scrolled .plz check and suggest me how to do it :)

Comment: slider_label_1 and relativeLayout2 are missing... Where are them?

Comment: ignore them buddy.the xml is working fine..actually i changed it lots of times.removed and added things..so i forgot to remve them...just tell me the way.keep those things tere only .

Comment: Bro.its still not working..bottom part still not able to scroll

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90157/discussion-between-developer-and-hussein-el-feky).